# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||=' in ClassViewer.js

Tags: javascript, typescript

Ireceive this error and I am unsure what I need to do to resolve it. It is default in a classViewer.js so not sure if I should change the code or update something. I am not sure what ||= even means.

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ tsc --noEmit && eslint . --ext .ts --fix

Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.56.0

/Users/mpatel1/Documents/Repos/liberty-retail-api/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/scope-manager/dist/referencer/ClassVisitor.js:123
        withMethodDecorators ||=
                             ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||='
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mpatel1/Documents/Repos/liberty-retail-api/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/scope-manager/dist/referencer/Referencer.js:20:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
```

Code:

```
withMethodDecorators ||=
            methodNode.kind !== 'set' &&
                node.params.some(param => param.decorators.length);
```

Comment: `withMethodDecorators = withMethodDecorators ||   ( methodNode.kind !== 'set' && node.params.some(param => param.decorators.length) );`

Comment: You've got some old software somewhere that doesn't understand the `||=` operator.

Comment: That seemed to be the issue, node needed to be updated. Thanks guys